# MySQL Between Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a small help in mysql. Following is my table structure

[image]

I just wanted to know how can I get a result from 5/30/2011 to 6/30/2011 with a proper sql query. I tried with Between query but its not working.

Thanks

Mujahid

Comment: What datatype is the `startdate` and `enddate` fields in? Also: Should the entire event be held inside that timespan or is it enough that some part of it is?

Comment: what type of filed is ``startdate`` ?

Comment: @Emil & Mihai: sorry guys the datatype was varchar :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE startdate > '5/30/2011' AND  startdate < '6/30/2011'
```

(assuming your using date datatype for startdate)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working though I just changed the query second data as follows: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE startdate >= '5/30/2011` AND enddate <= '6/30/2011'`

Now its working. Thanks :)

Comment: Ooops got another problem, since its not a date type, I am getting some issue, is there a way to change the column type to date and convert all the current strings to date. Someone else has created this database and I'm now getting stuck on it :(

Comment: You will need to insert everything into a temp table then alter the original table, truncate then insert back into it. If you open a new question i will write the syntax for you.

Comment: Hi Tom, I created a new one right now, can you pls answer in that one. Thanks. check the link here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090231/how-to-convert-a-varchar-column-type-to-date-type-without-losing-the-dates