# How to convert a varchar column type to date type without losing the dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to change the datatype of a column. Currently, in my database, the date columns types were defined as varchar and I need to convert them back to the date type.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: This is the current format: 4/9/2011 (m/d/y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to adapt this based your your exact table structure but something like;

```
CREATE TABLE temp (startdate varchar(255), stuff varchar(255));

INSERT INTO temp
SELECT startdate,stuff
FROM mytable;

TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN startdate DATETIME NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT CAST(startdate AS DATETIME), stuff FROM temp;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

Comment: I did it, but at the end, the datetime column values changed to NULL :(

Comment: the current date format in varchar column is : 4/9/2011 (m/d/y)

Comment: Does SELECT CAST(startdate AS DATETIME), stuff FROM temp; return null for that column too?

Comment: yes, I think we should use STR_TO_DATE(startdate,format) right?

Comment: @Tome: Thanks a lot mate, now its working. following is the code 
`INSERT INTO mytable SELECT id, STR_TO_DATE(startdate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(enddate,'%m/%d/%Y'), tname,handicap, club, url
FROM temp;`

If you haven't provide the above code structure, I wont be able to do it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: HI Tom, please let me know one more thing, how can I update only 1 column data taking from another table as from the above method

Comment: @Mujahid I dont understand what your asking. Can you open a new question going into detail what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

First, create the new column with type data
Next, run update query, to populate the new column with the value of the old one, applying any conversion if needed
Next, drop the old column
Finally, rename the new column to the old one

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new DATE column with a temporary name
2. Populate the new column with an UPDATE query that makes use of [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
3. If everything's right, remove the VARCHAR column and rename the DATE column.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql  default date format is : YYYY-MM-DD . If your try to insert the date otherwise, as you actually did, the date will be inserted with these values : 000-00-00, giving you a hint to the acceptable date format for mySql.

Answer (score 0):

Wanna share this for SQL server users. For me this method is much convenient and safer.

1. In your Table create new column "NewDate" (temporarily or name whatever you want).
2. Make sure no invalid Datetime format in the Table you want to convert. Try those formats here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_cast3 <--- you need to check thoroughly otherwise there would be an error executing the command below.
3. Execute this command:

UPDATE myTable 
SET NewDate = CAST(OldDate AS datetime)
WHERE     (OldDate <> '') AND (OldDate IS NOT NULL) --to make sure you cast only what is needed otherwise there would be an error.

4. You can now delete the old column i.e. "OldDate".
5. Finally you can drag and drop the new table you've created to the slot where you just deleted the old column in the table design.

Answer (score 0):

If the field of your column is `VARCHAR` and stored date as `DD-MM-YYYY` then we have to convert the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format by following PHP code.

```
$cd = array();

$cd1 = array();

$cdf = array();

$getdata = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT columnname FROM tablename");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getdata))        
{   
    $cd = $row['columnname'];

    $cd1 = strtotime($cd);

    $cdf = date('Y-m-d',$cd1);

    mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE tablename SET columnname = 
    REPLACE(columnname,'$cd','$cdf')");
}
```

After running this PHP code, in your MySQL table change the datatype of your column to `'DATE'`.
It works for me without losing or truncate data.