# Find the time difference between two datetime columns stored as varchar

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have a table column named `date_created` where I store datetime values in VARCHAR e.g. `16-06-2013 10:49:29`

I want to get results through mysql query between tow dates. I am using query like this:

```
... WHERE date_created BETWEEN '06-08-2013 22:30:18' AND '28-08-2013 22:30:22' ...
```

This query return results but that result also includes older date records that are `between 06 and 28` of every month. I also use < and > but these also did not work.

How can I get results that only include records between '06-08-2013 22:30:18' AND '28-08-2013 22:30:22'

Comment: Why are you storing it in a `varchar`?  Use [the correct data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson. I know these datatypes. But I have done a mistake by using VARCHAR for date. Can I convert VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: You should do it one time to migrate your data so you can query properly.  If you try to do it during the query, you will not be able to build the proper index and will suffer a performance hit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090231/how-to-convert-a-varchar-column-type-to-date-type-without-losing-the-dates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use MySQL-function STR_TO_DATE to format strings into DATETIME.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('06-08-2013 22:30:18', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
# 2013-08-06 22:30:18
```

I would recommend to reformat all VARCHARs to DATETIMEs with a single UPDATE and fix the code.

Comment: reformat all VARCHARs to DATETIMEs. What is that single update?

Comment: UPDATE ... SET date_created = STR_TO_DATE(date_created, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
And after this alter the column to be a DATETIME

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert your date string into a date that can be used for comparisons.

```
STR_TO_DATE(date_created, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('06-08-2013 22:30:18', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('28-08-2013 22:30:22', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```